# how can we use css in gwt with string matching, like google searching

Tags: gwt

I am new in gwt . I am devloping searching widget. i want when a user type in text box ,suggested string will be show to user and some character show in bold ,which are enter by the user like in google searching ..![image]

please help me..

```
 TextBox fnametextbox=new TextBox();

    Label l = new Label("search");

    VerticalPanel p = new VerticalPanel();

    public void onModuleLoad() 
    {
            fnametextbox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPress());

            RootPanel.get().add(l);

            RootPanel.get().add(fnametextbox);
    }
    public class KeyPress implements KeyPressHandler
    {
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event)      
        {
            String ab =fnametextbox.getText();

            if(ab.length()>1)
                {
                    greetingService.infouser(ab,new AsyncCallback<String>()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                                    {
                                        Window.alert("Invalid");
                                    }


                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(String result) 
                                    { 
                                        System.out.println(result);

                                        if(result==gresult)
                                            { 
                                                System.out.println("result");

                                                p.clear();

                                                Label lii = new Label("not found");

                                                p.setVisible(true);

                                                p.setBorderWidth(1);

                                                p.add(lii);

                                                RootPanel.get().add(p);
                                            }
                                        else
                                            {
                                                p.clear();

                                                p.setVisible(false);

                                                p.setVisible(true);

                                                p.setBorderWidth(1);

                                                int l=0;

                                                for (String retval: result.split("/"))
                                                    {
                                                        if(l==0)
                                                            {
                                                                Anchor an = new Anchor(retval,
                                                                        false,
                                                                        "http://localhost:8080/w1/",
                                                                        "_blank");
                                                                        p.add(an);
                                                                        l++;
                                                            }
                                                        else 
                                                            {
                                                                Label an=new Label(retval);
                                                                p.add(an);
                                                                l--;
                                                            }

                                                        RootPanel.get().add(p);
                                                    }   
                                                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [SuggestBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) that provide this functionality in-build?

[image]

---

--EDIT--

use different constructor of [Anchor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) that accepts [SafeHtml](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtml.html).

- Look at this constructor of [Anchor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#Anchor%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Sample code

```
String retval = "en<b>glish to hindi</b>";

Anchor anchor = new Anchor(retval, true, "http://localhost:8080/w1/", "_blank");
```

Sample code: (dynamically change the value in html)

```
String match = "en";
String result = "english to hindi/english speaking/english grammer/english songs";

for (String retval : result.split("/")) {
    String html = retval.replaceAll(match, "<b>" + match + "</b>");
    System.out.println(html);
    Anchor an = new Anchor(html, true, "http://localhost:8080/w1/", "_blank");
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Not a good design to fetch the result separated by slash. What about if slash is searched?

Comment: no I use only simple text box and vertical panel with show and hide method

Comment: i am getting my suggested string from mysql

Comment: ok but its a static change after enter two character remaning string become bold but I want like a google searching where character become bold after string matching .

Comment: Do you how to find a substring that is matched from the result? If yes then you can form a html based on matching text and pass it to Anchor as html.

Comment: use `new Anchor(html, true, "http://localhost:8080/w1/", "_blank")`. Pass `true` in constructor.